Bug description: We couldn't locate login screen
Updated iPhone app was rejected by App Review. Bug Description: We couldn't locate login screen. Review device details:
Device type: iPad Air (5th generation)
OS version: iOS 17.5.1

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue? The same app, but in different language, was accepted by App Review. Thanks all for looking into it.
There are no issues with the app when running it on Xcode simulators and iOS devices.

Here is a complete description of the bug, which caused rejection of the iPhone/iPad app by App Review team:
Subject: Rejected app. REVIEW STATUS: 2.1.0 Performance: App Completeness. Bug description: We couldn’t locate login screen.
Does anyone know what locating login screen refers to and how to address the bug?
